# How to test the membership in a many-to-many relation in Rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, many-to-many

For example, one user has joined many group; and one group has many user members. Now I get a user object and a group object, I want to know whether this user is a member of this group.

I can see some methods, but still wandering whether there is a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, if i understand your question, what you have is something like:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :groups, :though => :user_members

class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users, :though => :user_members
```

And you want to know if a user is a member of a specific group.

So, given something like:

```
u = User.first
g = Group.first
```

Just do:

```
u.groups.include? g
```

Thats all there is to it!

ian.

Answer (score 0):

ipd's way is fine, another more Rails oriented way to do it is :

```
u.groups.exists?(g)
```